# Existence of $h\in\mathcal{F}(C_c^{\infty})$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}h(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $\chi(\xi)\in C_{c}^{\infty}(B(0,1))$, such that $\chi(\xi)=1$
for $\left|\xi\right|\le1/2$. Let $h=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\chi$, the
inverse Fourier transform of $\chi$. If it is possible that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}h(x)\mathrm{d}x=1?
$$
which means
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{B(0,1)}\chi(\xi)\cos(\xi x)\mathrm{d} \xi\mathrm{d} x=1?
$$
Does this $\chi$ exists?

I calculate in $1D$, in $(-l,l)$ for any $l>0$, we know that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-l}^{l}\cos(\xi x)\mathrm{d}\xi\mathrm{d}x=2\pi
$$
which is much bigger than $1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm but the value of $\chi$ in $B(0,1/2)$ is fixed to be $1$..

Comment: $\chi$ is the Fourier transform of $h$, i.e. $\chi(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}h(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\,dx$. Hence $\chi(0)=\int_{\mathbb R^d} h(x)\,dx$. Since $\chi(0)=1$, we have $\int_{\mathbb R^d} h(x)\,dx=1$. Therefore, we only need to construct $\chi$ satisfying the conditions of $\chi$. Don’t worry about $h$, since the property of $h$ is a consequence of properties of $\chi$.

Comment: @Feng, oh, thx, I just run in a wrong direction...